# XML to table using ssis

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012, ssis, dts

I was trying to laod an xml file(.xml) to table using ssis xml source components.
as there is no inline schema present inside my xml file,i was trying to  generate the 
xsd file from the existing xml file..but it shows an error that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x14ac" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac"><dimension ref="A1:C25"/><sheetViews><sheetView workbookViewId="0"><selection activeCell="B4" sqref="B4"/></sheetView></sheetViews><sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/><cols><col min="1" max="1" width="13" bestFit="1" customWidth="1"/><col min="2" max="2" width="100.5703125" customWidth="1"/><col min="3" max="3" width="11.28515625" bestFit="1" customWidth="1"/></cols><sheetData><row r="1" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A1" s="1" t="s"><v>0</v></c><c r="B1" s="1" t="s"><v>778</v></c><c r="C1" s="1" t="s"><v>802</v></c></row><row r="2" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A2" s="2"><v>100</v></c><c r="B2" s="2" t="s"><v>803</v></c><c r="C2" s="2"><v>1</v></c></row><row r="3" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A3" s="2"><v>101</v></c><c r="B3" s="2" t="s"><v>779</v></c><c r="C3" s="2"><v>1</v></c></row><row r="4" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A4" s="2"><v>102</v></c><c r="B4" s="2" t="s"><v>780</v></c><c r="C4" s="2"><v>1</v></c></row><row r="5" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A5" s="2"><v>201</v></c><c r="B5" s="2" t="s"><v>781</v></c><c r="C5" s="2"><v>2</v></c></row><row r="6" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A6" s="2"><v>301</v></c><c r="B6" s="2" t="s"><v>782</v></c><c r="C6" s="2"><v>3</v></c></row><row r="7" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A7" s="2"><v>302</v></c><c r="B7" s="2" t="s"><v>783</v></c><c r="C7" s="2"><v>3</v></c></row><row r="8" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A8" s="2"><v>303</v></c><c r="B8" s="2" t="s"><v>784</v></c><c r="C8" s="2"><v>3</v></c></row><row r="9" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A9" s="2"><v>304</v></c><c r="B9" s="2" t="s"><v>785</v></c><c r="C9" s="2"><v>3</v></c></row><row r="10" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A10" s="2"><v>305</v></c><c r="B10" s="2" t="s"><v>786</v></c><c r="C10" s="2"><v>3</v></c></row><row r="11" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A11" s="2"><v>401</v></c><c r="B11" s="2" t="s"><v>787</v></c><c r="C11" s="2"><v>4</v></c></row><row r="12" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A12" s="2"><v>402</v></c><c r="B12" s="2" t="s"><v>788</v></c><c r="C12" s="2"><v>4</v></c></row><row r="13" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A13" s="2"><v>501</v></c><c r="B13" s="2" t="s"><v>789</v></c><c r="C13" s="2"><v>5</v></c></row><row r="14" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A14" s="2"><v>601</v></c><c r="B14" s="2" t="s"><v>790</v></c><c r="C14" s="2"><v>6</v></c></row><row r="15" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A15" s="2"><v>901</v></c><c r="B15" s="2" t="s"><v>791</v></c><c r="C15" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row><row r="16" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A16" s="2"><v>902</v></c><c r="B16" s="2" t="s"><v>792</v></c><c r="C16" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row><row r="17" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A17" s="2"><v>903</v></c><c r="B17" s="2" t="s"><v>793</v></c><c r="C17" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row><row r="18" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A18" s="2"><v>904</v></c><c r="B18" s="2" t="s"><v>794</v></c><c r="C18" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row><row r="19" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A19" s="2"><v>905</v></c><c r="B19" s="2" t="s"><v>795</v></c><c r="C19" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row><row r="20" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A20" s="2"><v>906</v></c><c r="B20" s="2" t="s"><v>796</v></c><c r="C20" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row><row r="21" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A21" s="2"><v>907</v></c><c r="B21" s="2" t="s"><v>797</v></c><c r="C21" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row><row r="22" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A22" s="2"><v>908</v></c><c r="B22" s="2" t="s"><v>798</v></c><c r="C22" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row><row r="23" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A23" s="2"><v>909</v></c><c r="B23" s="2" t="s"><v>799</v></c><c r="C23" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row><row r="24" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A24" s="2"><v>910</v></c><c r="B24" s="2" t="s"><v>800</v></c><c r="C24" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row><row r="25" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"><c r="A25" s="2"><v>911</v></c><c r="B25" s="2" t="s"><v>801</v></c><c r="C25" s="2"><v>8</v></c></row></sheetData><sortState ref="A2:C25"><sortCondition ref="A2:A25"/></sortState><pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/></worksheet>
```

unable to infer xsd from xml as xml containe multiple name spaces

Comment: you may need to remove some namespaces to be able to generate the xsd. Can you provide a sample of the xml including the declarations?

Comment: i have posted it ..please see  above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the namespaces so the declaration is just  
Also plesse remove all the occurrences of "x14ac:"  then you will be able to generate the xsd in SSIS.

After you have the xsd you can then go back to the original xml (i.e with the namespaces) and it will still work fine with the generated xsd.